# attempt to call method 'applyForce' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
function spawnRBird( x,y )  
    print("\n entered into spawnred");
    rBird = display.newSprite (sheet, seqData);
    rBird.x = x;
    rBird.y = y;
    rBird:setSequence("rBird")
    rBird.anchorX = 0;
    rBird.anchorY = 1;
    physics.addBody(rBird, "dynamic", {density=1, bounce=0.5, friction=0.5})
    rBird:play();
    rBird:addEventListener( "collision", birdCollision );
```

I am getting:

> attempt to call method 'applyForce' (a nil value)

when I click on the screen after spawning red bird `rBird` object inside `rBirdJump` is becoming nil please explain in corona lua

```
function rBirdJump( event )
    if (event.phase == "began") then
            rBird:applyForce(0, -50, redBird.x, redBird.y)
            rBird:setLinearVelocity( 0, -10 )
            rBird.isFixedRotation = true;
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", rBirdJump);
--timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function Runtime:addEventListener("touch", rBirdJump) end, 1 )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for a fact that `spawnRBird` is being called before you touch the screen? Also the message indicates that `rBird` is not nil but that `applyForce` is not a method on `rBird`. This implies that rBird has been removed from physics after being spawned, or removed as a display object (which does not make it nil, just removes certain methods from it).

If this doesn't help you find the problem you will have to post the file as you have it instead of just portions.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because **rBird** is not a physics object when the function is called. 
In your **spawnBird** function, you are initializing rBird and adding it to physics. You are declaring rBird to be a global variable. This is generally a bad programming practice and should not be adapted because it might lead to major memory leaks.

You can initialize rBird in the function as a local variable and use a local variable to the scene / current file to avoid using globals. Set the variable same as rBird after you have added it in physics so that your jump function wont return an error. This would also help you in making sure that your variable to display object is being used after it is added in the physics engine.

```
-- forward reference to your created redBird. Initialize as nil to make sure the variable is assigned a value after its added in physics.
local redBird = nil
function spawnRBird( x,y )  
    print("\n entered into spawnred");
    local rBird = display.newSprite (sheet, seqData);
    rBird.x = x;
    rBird.y = y;
    rBird:setSequence("rBird")
    rBird.anchorX = 0;
    rBird.anchorY = 1;
    physics.addBody(rBird, "dynamic", {density=1, bounce=0.5, friction=0.5})
    redBird = rBird
    rBird:play();
    rBird:addEventListener( "collision", birdCollision );
```

By using the variable redBird in the later code, you can make sure that you are using a phusics object as you are assigning it a value after it is added in physics.

```
function rBirdJump( event )
    if (event.phase == "began" and redBird ~= nil) then
        redBird:applyForce(0, -50, redBird.x, redBird.y)
        redBird:setLinearVelocity( 0, -10 )
        redBird.isFixedRotation = true;
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", rBirdJump);
--timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function Runtime:addEventListener("touch", rBirdJump) end, 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have started the physics:

```
physics.start();
```